# Total special values earned with frequency in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

I have a 2D matrix of order (M x N) where all cells contain 0 except K special cells which contain a special value say 1. Now I need to start at the cell say (0, 0) and reach the cell (M-1, N-1). I can move only in right or down direction from any cell. Now I need to find on every successful reach at the (M-1, N-1) cell, how many special values I have collected and what is their frequency? Example: I can have say 3 paths which contains only one special value, I have 10 path which contain 2 special values ... and so on.

I need to print all possible pairs of total special value earned with corresponding frequency i.e; (2, 10) - means there are 2 paths which gave a total special value of 10 each etc.

It seems like to find out all dfs path from source to destination and count the frequencies of total special values earned from source to destination. But it is having very high time complexity.

How to minimize the time complexity or if possible how to use dynamic programming concept here?

Example:

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 0 0
```

- Here, there are 2 paths with total special value = 2, only 1 path with a total of special value = 0, 3 paths with special value = 1 etc.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output for the problem?

Comment: @abhishekbafna , kindly see the post, just added an example.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem it's pretty easy to eliminate possible paths, by simply transforming the graph.

Transform the matrix into a directed graph, where each node is one special value. Each node `(nx , ny)` is only connected with other nodes `(mx , my)`, that match `nx <= mx && ny <= my && !(nx == mx && ny == my)`

```
    int[][] matrix = getMatrix()
    int specialNumberCount = specialNumberCount()
    int m = getM(), n = getN()

    list points

    for int x in [0 , m[
        for int y in [0 , n[
            if(matrix[x][y] == specialValue())
                points.add(point(x , y));

    int[][] adjacencSpecial = new int[specialNumberCount][specialNumberCount];
    for int i in [0 , length(points)[
        point p = points.get(i)

        for int j in [0 , length(points)[
            if j == i
                continue
            else
                point s = points.get(j)
                if p.x <= s.x AND p.y <= s.y AND (p.x != s.x AND p.y != s.y)
                    adjacencMatrix[i][j] = 1
```

Now this code reduces the size of the graph from `M x N` to `K`. From this point it shouldn't take too long to run a BFS.

Comment: can you please write the last few lines properly in your code?

Comment: for int j in distinct([0 , length(points)[ , [i])
            if y.x == n.x AND p.y <= n.y

Comment: But after making the adjacent matrix, how can I get the result as described in the question. I need all paths with any achievable special values along with their frequencies.

Comment: You'll have to do that part with some graph analysation. This answer only provides a way to reduce the graph-size and thus speed up the search. You'll have to do the counting itself using DFS or BFS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need it, but found a very fast way of doing it (time complexity less than `O(W+H)`):

First, you find the number of possible paths by finding the binomial coefficient of the no of moves by the number of moves toward right ( `c(W+H-2,W-1)` ), then iterate throught each path, storing the points for later use.
Code:

```
//
//  main.c
//
//  Created by Xavier L'Heureux on 15-10-01.
//
//  This code return the number of path for each possible value in the matrix where you can only
//   go down or right.
//
//  Note that this code work also for for non-square matrices
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define W 3
#define H 4

int matrix[W][H] = {
    {0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,1,1},
    {0,0,0,0}
};

int path(double p, double n){
    int x = W - 1, y = H - 1;
    int points = 0;
    while (x != 0 || y != 0){
        //printf("\np: %f\nn: %f\n", p, n);
        if (x == 0){
            y --;
            points += matrix[x][y];
        } else if (y == 0){
            x --;
            points += matrix[x][y];
        } else if (p / n >= y / (double)(x + y)){
            p -= n * y / (x + y);
            n -= n * y / (x + y);
            points += matrix[x][y];
            x --;
        } else {
            n -= n * x / (x + y);
            points += matrix[x][y];
            y --;
        }
    }
    return points;
}

double c(int n, int k){
    double x = 1.0;
    int i;
    for (i = n; i > (n-k); i--){
        x *= i;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++){
        x /= i;
    }
    return x;
}

int numOfPoints(){
    int points = 0;
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < W; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < W; y++) {
            points += matrix[x][y];
        }
    }
    return points;
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = c(W + H - 2, W - 1);
    printf("%d path(s)",n);
    int maxPoints = numOfPoints() + 1;
    int *countPtr = (int *)calloc(maxPoints, sizeof (int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        countPtr[path(i, n)]++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= maxPoints; i++){
       printf("n° of path(s) with %d point(s) : \t%d\n", i, countPtr[i]);
    }
    free(countPtr);
    return 0;
}
```